# predicateWithFormat is very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am running a predicate in a coredata NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification to filter relevant objects I am interested in.

```
  - (void)didSaveNotficiation:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
            NSSet *objects = nil;
            NSMutableSet *combinedSet = nil;
            NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

            NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

            objects = [userInfo objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
            combinedSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:objects];

            objects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
            [combinedSet unionSet:objects];

            objects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
            [combinedSet unionSet:objects];

//THis is slow
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name == %@ && %K == %@",
                                                         [XXContact entityName], XXContactRelationship.user,self];
            [combinedSet filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

            if ([combinedSet count] == 0) {
                return;
            }

            [self process];

/* This is much faster
            [combinedSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[XXContact class]]) {
                    XXContact* contact = (XXContact*)obj;
                    if (contact.user == self) {
                        [self process];
                        *stop = YES;
                    }
                }
            }];
*/
}
```

The notification can be called over 100 times when the app starts. 
When I profile the app, it seems that the function predicateWithFormat is so slow that is taking up 20% of cpu. It is not even the filtering that is slow. The creation of the predicate itself is so slow. 
If I change it to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, it becomes much faster, but the code is less readable.

Does anyone has a explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot beat the time achieved by your enumeration filtering using your current predicate for a few reasons:

1. You are allocating, parsing and composing the predicate at each call to `didSaveNotficiation :`
2. You use string comparison in your predicate which is much more costly then 'isKindOfClass:' class
3. You have a stop condition in your implementation which is not possible in a predicate (all objects in `combinedSet` will have to be evaluated)
4. Your predicate filtering execution is mutating the set (removing objects)

**I believe that your best option is implementing the predicate yourself**

To improve on your predicate implementation I would suggest:

```
//1. change .name property to an Integer/Enum value
//2. make your predicate static and reduce the compose and parse needs:
//(If you must use %K in your predicate this would be much harder)
//NOT TESTED
static NSPredicate* p = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name == $ENAME AND user == $USEROBJECT"];
});

NSPredicate* currPredicate = [p predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"ENAME" : [XXContact entityName], @"USEROBJECT" : [self objectID]}];
[combinedSet filterUsingPredicate:currPredicate];
```

As you can see, if you try to improve readability is impaired.